# 'Real Time' data methods MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I've recently been researching data transfer methods that could replace my current inefficient setup.

So just to get started I will explain the issue that I am having with my current MySQL data transfer method...

I have a database that keeps track of product inventory levels within my warehouses, this stock data is constantly changing at a rapid rate.

A CSV file is created and set to cron every 15 minutes, I then delivery this CSV file via FTP to multiple sites that we manage to update inventory stock levels. These sites are also using MySQL and the data in the CSV file is added with a script.

This method is very inefficient and doesn't update our stock levels to our other databases as fast as we would like.

My question is are there any other methods to transfer MySQL data in real time between multiple databases other than CSV files? I have been researching another method however haven't came across anything useful as of yet.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that you are having multiple MySQL databases and you want them copying (replicating) their own data to the others at real time (or a much faster pace)?

Comment: Yes Luca that is my issue

Comment: Before trying to figure out a way doing this, let me ask you a few question about why you need it. Does the data has to be physically replicated to every databases? Is it okay to access the data remotely so that you don't need any replication at all? How will users access data in database, through some web frontend, dump data to a CSV file, or something else?